# Shell script source on non-existing file terminates the script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix

Consider Below:

```
#!/bin/sh

# GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release
echo "Start"
cd /path/does/not/exists # this does not terminate
source /path/does/not/exists

echo $?
echo "End"
```

Result:

```
Start
./test.sh: line 6: /path/does/not/exists: No such file or directory
```

Why none of the `echo`s print anything and script terminates? why only `source` error is caught without setting explicit `set -e` and terminates the script?

Comment: You're not running/using `bash` but `sh`.

Comment: /bin/sh is a symlink to bash

Comment: It does not matter , Mine too. Try running it with `bash ./myscript`

Comment: ok - would you please explain why using `sh`  vs `bash` make a difference?

Comment: `sh` is not `bash` ? But there might be some POSIX compatibily/compliant along the lines somewhere in there though.

Comment: `bash --posix ./myscript` should give you the same error as `sh` so POSIX ...

Comment: @pmoubed, because `bash` [enters POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) when invoked as `sh`. If you want to use `bash`, you'll need to be explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When running in posix mode, `bash` will abort if the file named as the argument to `.` (aka `source`) does not exist.  See: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18

> If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an
> interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error,
> but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.

Since you have used `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang, bash is [running in posix mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html).  From the `bash` manpage:

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
> behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible,  while
> conforming  to the  POSIX standard as well.